# Visual Studio 2017 node version overrides nvm use version

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, nvm

I'm trying to learn `Angular` using `asp.net core 2.0`, since I have no experience with `Node.js` I'm trying to set up my environment using `nvm`, which I installed using `chocolatey` (just in case it makes a difference), as recommended by a friend, the tutorial I'm following tells me to use `node 6.9.0` and have installed it and set it as active:

```
nvm install 6.9.0
nvm ls
nvm use 6.9.0
```

and I get the proper message telling me `6.9.0` is the active version. However when I do:

```
node --version
```

I get

```
v8.10.0
```

I use Visual Studio 2017 Pro for my everyday work, and I know it comes with its own version of node and I'm guessing that's what I'm seeing here and probably nvm will have no control over it as it not shown on the list of installed versions, and I know I haven't installed it myself. So my questions are:

What do I have to do to use the version I set with nvm?

Once I have that ready, what do I need to do to have VS use that version instead of its own?

Answer (score 1):

I just worked out how to fix this, I'm posting an answer to help anyone else struggling with this, apparently, VS (or maybe myself **:-(** ) installed node directly and the one sitting on `C:\Program Files\Nodejs` was indeed version `8.10.0` and nvm was unable to change override it, so I just uninstalled the standalone node and ran the above commands on nvm and it worked like a charm.